# XMLHttpRequest progress event total = 0

Tags: javascript, php, http, xmlhttprequest, content-length

I'm creating a progress bar for a XMLHttpRequest that loads some data with PHP, but the progress event shows a total of 0

This is my code:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest 
xhr.open('POST','../XML/ap.re.load.php')
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded",true);
xhr.send('id ='+lastid)
xhr.addEventListener('progress',(e) =>{
    console.log(e);
})
xhr.onload = () => {
}
```

Comment: what's the value of the content-length header in the response?

Comment: try setting progress listener before send

Comment: still not working @James

Comment: There is no content-length on the response @bel3atar

Comment: Does it work ok without the progress listener?  If not, make the rest work well first.

Comment: the request is working

Answer (score 0):

For progress event to work properly you should have a `Content-Length` header inside the response headers. The value of this header is used to populate the `total` value in the progress event. If the header is missing the total value will be missing from the event.

If the `Content-Length` header is missing from your response it could be because the file is being sent "chunked" (Check the `Transfer-Encoding` header in the response for value `chunked`).

In this case the `Content-Length` header is omitted.

See for reference on this topic [this page about Transfer-Encoding on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#directives):

> Data is sent in a series of chunks. The Content-Length header is omitted in this case...

We resolved this in our case by adding a custom `X-File-Length` header to the response and used that as a fallback for the `total` value when calculating the progress.